# what's the right Windows folder to exchange data between local users?

Tags: windows, security, windows-7, permissions, windows-xp

I want to write a file in app running under local regular user account and read it in service. What's the right folder?

I'd like to avoid `%APPDATA%` (`CSIDL_APPDATA`) folder because service would need to realize where's this folder are (service is running under system account). I checked `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` (is it `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`?), it points to `c:\ProgramData` on my Win7 x64. But this folder doesn't allows modification for regular local users (I checked in folder `properties`, `security` tab). The same about `%CommonProgramFiles%`.

I need to support WinXP and up.

Comment: I know that it's an old thread, but I'm curious how did you resolve this issue? Indeed `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` points to a different folder from a service. Does `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` indeed point to the same location everywhere you call it from (service, user-mode app, guest account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` (or `FOLDERID_PublicDocuments`), that is the Shared Documents folder.  Under XP it would be something like `c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents`.

Comment: I was in the same situation and the correct answer is actually to use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`, especially if the shared folder is required from a service. In case of a service (or session 0 process) you will not be able to get `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS`.

Answer (score 2):

I found no such folder when I was in similar situation. The simple solution is to create a folder in CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA folder during installation (or from the service) with special permissions that allow normal users to write to this folder.